# If the value is a number between x and y, change it to z (pd df)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider:

```
data.loc[data.cig_years (10 < a < 20), 'cig_years'] = 1
```

This is the code I have tried, but it's not working. In pseudocode I want:

```
In the df 'data'
    In the column 'cig_years'
        If the value is a number between 10 and 20, change it to 1
```

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this? Preferably without *for* loops.

Comment: please follow guidelines here in posting a questions to help contributors in their response  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got you. You can filter pandas dataframes with square brackets []:

```
data['cig_years'] [ (data['cig_years']>10) | (data['cig_years']<20) ] = 1
```

This basically says:

The columns 'cig_years' in data, where the columns 'cig_years' is more than 10, or less than, is set equal to 1

This is super useful in pandas dataframes because you can filter for specific columns, or filter by conditions on other columns, and then set those filtered values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your dataframe name "data" and change it using .loc like below:

```
data.loc[10 < data['cig_years'] < 20, 'cig_years'] = 1
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this but I get the error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an np.where statement
This statement assumes you are going to leave the cig years alone if it is not between 10 and 20

```
data['cig_years'] = np.where(10 < data['cig_years'] < 20, 1, data['cig_years'])
```